# Trying to avoid nesting Select statements but getting error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int"

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first part of my code below defines the field 'LCO'.  I am trying to use that field in the second part to check if result of the SELECT is greater than the 'LCO' corresponding field.

```
SELECT 
    Jobs.jmpPartID,
    Jobs.jmpJobID,
    Jobs.ujmpProjRelReference,
    Jobs.jmpCustomerOrganizationID,
    Jobs.jmpProductionQuantity,
    Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate,
    (SELECT 
         ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID
                 FROM M1_HB.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
                 WHERE JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
                   AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = -1
                 ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID DESC), 0)) AS 'LCO',
    (SELECT TOP 1 WorkCenters.xawProductionDepartmentID
    FROM M1_HB.dbo.WorkCenters WorkCenters,
         M1_Hb.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
    WHERE WorkCenters.xawWorkCenterID = JobOperations.jmoWorkCenterID
      AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete=0
      AND JobOperations.jmoJobID =Jobs.jmpJobID
      AND JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID > 'LCO'
    ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID) AS 'Dept'
FROM 
    M1_HB.dbo.Jobs Jobs
WHERE 
    (Jobs.jmpProductionComplete = 0)
ORDER BY 
    Jobs.jmpPartID, Jobs.jmpJobID
```

I am getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to datatype int

If I nest the first `SELECT` into the second (ie replace > 'LCO' with > (Select Isnull((Select Top 1 .....)) like below then it works.

```
SELECT 
    Jobs.jmpPartID,
    Jobs.jmpJobID,
    Jobs.ujmpProjRelReference,
    Jobs.jmpCustomerOrganizationID,
    Jobs.jmpProductionQuantity,
    Jobs.jmpProductionDueDate,
    (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID
                    FROM M1_HB.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
                    WHERE JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
                      AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = -1
                    ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID DESC), 0)) AS 'LCO',
    (SELECT TOP 1 WorkCenters.xawProductionDepartmentID
     FROM M1_HB.dbo.WorkCenters WorkCenters,
          M1_Hb.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
     WHERE WorkCenters.xawWorkCenterID = JobOperations.jmoWorkCenterID
       AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = 0 
       AND JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
       AND JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID > (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID
                                                             FROM M1_HB.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
                                                             WHERE JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
                                                               AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = -1
                                                             ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID DESC), 0))
     ORDER BY 
         JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID) AS 'Dept'
FROM 
    M1_HB.dbo.Jobs Jobs
WHERE 
    (Jobs.jmpProductionComplete = 0)
ORDER BY 
    Jobs.jmpPartID, Jobs.jmpJobID
```

What do I need to do to my first code to make it work?  I tried using `CAST()` in various ways, but without success

Comment: Can't you simplify the code so it makes sense to someone who has never seen this code before?

Comment: If I need to side-scroll code, I just skip the question.

Comment: Use [this](https://sqlformat.org/) to format your code.

Comment: Also, it does not work as you expect it in T-SQL. The `'LCO'` is not a known column at this point. You would need an outer `SELECT` and only then could you filter based on `'LCO'` which would be a known column of the result set.

Comment: Thanks for the info Rigerta.  Much appreciated

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, here you need to add two colums to a table in succession.
I would use CTE:

```
;WITH Jobs AS (
  SELECT
       jmpPartID,
       jmpJobID,
       ujmpProjRelReference,
       jmpCustomerOrganizationID,
       jmpProductionQuantity,
       jmpProductionDueDate,
      (SELECT isnull(
                   (SELECT top 1 JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID
                    FROM M1_HB.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
                    WHERE JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
                      AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = -1
                    ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID DESC)
      ,0)) AS LCO --< Step 1: add LCO column into Jobs CTE
  FROM M1_HB.dbo.Jobs
  WHERE jmpProductionComplete = 0
)
SELECT *,
  (SELECT Top 1 WorkCenters.xawProductionDepartmentID
   FROM M1_HB.dbo.WorkCenters WorkCenters,
        M1_Hb.dbo.JobOperations JobOperations
   WHERE WorkCenters.xawWorkCenterID = JobOperations.jmoWorkCenterID
     AND JobOperations.jmoProductionComplete = 0
     AND JobOperations.jmoJobID = Jobs.jmpJobID
     AND JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID > Jobs.LCO --< Now we do have LCO in Jobs
   ORDER BY JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID) AS Dept --< ... and can add dependent column
FROM Jobs
ORDER BY jmpPartID, jmpJobID
```

Comment: Y.B.  If I wanted to add an additional query to get another field using same comparison to Jobs.LCO how would I do that?  So above I retrieved the dept Id with SELECT Top 1 WorkCenters.xawProductionDepartmentID...   now I want the WorkCenterID (i.e. WorkCenters.xawWorkCenterID).

Comment: Just like you have `Dept` added you can add any number of dependant columns. If some of them are to be referenced too - keep wrapping CTEs in CTEs.

Comment: Thanks Y.B.  I figured it out.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Not at all. An off-topic advice. Do not hurry to accept an answer. Even if it is good and solves your problem there might be even better. And you might never see it because people would skip your question as "answered".

Comment: Duly Note.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `AND JobOperations.jmoJobOperationID > 'LCO'` tries to compare the obviously int value jmoJobOperationID against the string 'LCO' and for this tries to convert 'LCO' to int - therefore the error message. Furthermore, you can not access an alias of a column in the same query in which the alias is defined. Last but not least, why don't you want to use nested queries?

Comment: I didn't want to use nested queries, because I have other fields I need to pull with same conditions, so I didn't want to repeat the 'LCO' part